# How to speed up nested loop and add condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, loops

I am trying to speed up my nested loop it currently takes 15 mins for 100k customers.
I am also having trouble adding an additional condition that only multiplies states (A,B,C) by lookup2 val, else multiplies by 1.

```
customer_data = pd.DataFrame({"cust_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                              "state": ['B', 'E', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'A'],
                              "cust_amt": [1000,300, 500, 200, 400, 600, 200, 300],
                              "year":[3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4],
                              "group":[10, 25, 30, 40, 55, 60, 70, 85]})

state_list = ['A','B','C','D','E']

# All lookups should be dataframes with the year and/or group and the value like these.
lookup1 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                       'lim %': 0.1})
lookup2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'group':g, 'lookup_val': 0.1, 'year':range(1, 11)} 
                                  for g in customer_data['group'].unique())]).explode('year')

multi_data = np.arange(250).reshape(10,5,5)
```

```
lookups = [lookup1, lookup2]

# Preprocessing.
# Transform the state to categorical code to use it as array index.
customer_data['state'] = pd.Categorical(customer_data['state'], 
                                        categories=state_list, 
                                        ordered=True).codes

# Set index on lookups.
for i in range(len(lookups)):
    if 'group' in lookups[i].columns:
        lookups[i] = lookups[i].set_index(['year', 'group'])
    else:
        lookups[i] = lookups[i].set_index(['year'])
```

calculation:

```
results = {}
for customer, state, amount, start, group in customer_data.itertuples(name=None, index=False):
    for year in range(start, len(multi_data)+1):
        if year == start:
            results[customer] = [[amount * multi_data[year-1, state, :]]]
        else:
            results[customer].append([results[customer][-1][-1] @ multi_data[year-1]])
                
        for lookup in lookups:
            if isinstance(lookup.index, pd.MultiIndex):
                value = lookup.loc[(year, group)].iat[0]
            else:
                value = lookup.loc[year].iat[0]
            results[customer][-1].append(value * results[customer][-1][-1])
```

example of expected output:

```
{1: [[array([55000, 56000, 57000, 58000, 59000]),
   array([5500., 5600., 5700., 5800., 5900.]),
   array([550., 560., 570., 5800., 5900.])],...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiprocessing if you have more than one CPU.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def get_customer_data(data_tuple) -> dict:
    results = {}
    customer, state, amount, start, group = data_tuple
    for year in range(start, len(multi_data)+1):
        if year == start:
            results[customer] = [[amount * multi_data[year-1, state, :]]] 
        else:
            results[customer].append([results[customer][-1][-1] @ multi_data[year-1]])

        for lookup in lookups:
            if isinstance(lookup.index, pd.MultiIndex):
                value = lookup.loc[(year, group)].iat[0]
            else:
                value = lookup.loc[year].iat[0]
            results[customer][-1].append(value * results[customer][-1][-1])
    
    return results

p = Pool(mp.cpu_count())

# Pool.map() takes a function and an iterable like a list or generator
results_list = p.map(get_customer_data, [data_tuple for data_tuple in customer_data.itertuples(name=None, index=False)] )
# results is a list of dict()
results_dict = {k:v for x in results_list for k,v in x.items()}
p.close()
```

Comment: While multiprocessing could work it would be overkill for the kind of work happening here. Pandas can run very quickly if used correctly. I have seen 10+min runtimes go down to single digit seconds simply by minimising the use of loops in pandas

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see you posting this! As promised, my thoughts:

With Pandas works with columns very well. What you need to look to do is remove the need for loops as much as possible (In your case I would say get rid of the main loop you have then keep the year and lookups loop).

To do this, forget about the results{} variable for now. You want to do the calculations directly on the DataFrame. For example your first calculation would become something like:

```
customer_data['meaningful_column_name'] = [[amount * multi_data[customer_data['year']-1, customer_data['state'], :]]]
```

For your lookups loop you just have to be aware that the if statement will be looking at entire columns.

Finally, as it seems you want to have your data in a list of arrays you will need to do some formatting to extract the data from a DataFrame structure.

I hope that makes some sense

Comment: Sorry that's my bad. This should be closer to working: customer_data['meaningful_column_name'] = [[customer_data['amount'] * multi_data[year-1, customer_data['state'], :]]]. Also when something doesn't work please let use know what the error is.